# How to use Numeral.js or any JS plugins in React-Native App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, numeral.js

I need to change a number to currency format in React-Native
this doesn't work in my case:

```
import Numeral from "numeral";
Numeral(100).format("$0.00")
```

it outputs: Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error. 
I know Numeral is not built for React-Native, but is there a workaround or any alternative?

Comment: the documentation states (http://numeraljs.com/#use-it): `npm install numeral --dev` and then `const Numeral = require('numeral');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the step to use numeral library:

1. Do `npm install --save numeral` in your application folder
2. Import the numeral library like this `import numeral from 'numeral'`
3. Use it in the place that you want to put it like this `numeral(100).format('$0,0.00')`

You can see another type of format and documentation from the website http://numeraljs.com/